# How to configure Tomcat to use Windows NTLM authentication?

Tags: authentication, tomcat, active-directory

I would like to use  NTLM authentication with Tomcat so that Iexplorer send automatically both the user id+pwd to webapp.  Is this possible?

With "BASIC" authentication IE pops up the usual pwd dialog but I want to skip this dialog.   ( Note, I use JNDIReal/ldap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. The [Tomcat Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Windows#Q4) references a [documentation](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html) about Samba code that enables Tomcat to do NTLM authentication.

The Samba community implemented a Servlet filter that allows to athenticate users agains a domain controller.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's now possible with Waffle Tomcat Authenticator that supports Negotiate (NTLM v1, v2, etc., and Kerberos).

- Tutorial:
  http://code.dblock.org/ShowPost.aspx?id=103
- Waffle:
  http://dblock.github.io/waffle/

Waffle works on **windows server only**

Comment: Waffle is tomcat on windows only btw.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you're on a Windows server, you can have IIS do the authentication and redirect requests to Tomcat.  Here's the documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Answer (score 2):

- [JCIF](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html) is now (2011) deprecated (does not support NTLM v2).
- [JESPA](http://www.ioplex.com/jespa.html) is not free but may work out for you
- [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com) is windows server only

You may want to check out UnboundID's LDAP solution [www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/)
Haven't tried it yet but seems like a compromise.

Here is a quick comparison between UnboundID SDK, JNDI and Netscape SDK: [www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/advantages/comparison.php](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/docs/advantages/comparison.php) . It may be biased since it's on unbound's website but hey, gives you a good idea why you might consider it.

Answer (score 1):

people from the JCIFS project (the one reerenced in mkoller's answer) says that the solution they provide is not compatible with NTLMv2...

http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html

you should check http://www.ioplex.com/jespa.html, which is not free...

Comment: It appears the jespa library has a free version which "Supports an unlimited number of users for 60 days after which it will not authenticate more than 25 users."

Answer (score 1):

I have used JCIFS, Waffle and IIS side by side.

- JCIFS does not support NTLM v2, sometimes prompts users
- Waffle support NTLM v2, but sometimes prompts user
- IIS is the only solutio where promptless NTLM authentication works 100% of the time