# I want Domain Login in my web application

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on

i am developing web based HRIs application which is to be deployed on intranet and for dat m using

Frontend : jsp/servlets
Backend : Oracle
Application Server : Tomcat

in my web application i want domain login which means by tracing currently logged in user he should automatically logged in my web application

pl give me the possible solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439120/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-use-windows-ntlm-authentication

Answer (score 0):

If it's about single sign on you may find this [article](http://www.jajakarta.org/tomcat/tomcat3.2-4.0/tomcat-4.0b5/src/catalina/docs/singlesignon.html) about confguration helpful.

It describes how to use a valve which is configured in:

> $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml

by

```
 <Valve class="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn"/>
```

EDIT: A more current [resource regarding tomcat6](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Single%20Sign%20On)