# tomcat on windows server is asking users to log into server

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, waffle

I'm running a tomcat site on Windows 2012.  The site works for me ( I set it up on the server) but other users get a login prompt when they go to the site.  Any ideas?

The site uses Windows authentication.  At the moment I'm using my credentials for the tomcat service on the server.

UPDATE - I'm using Waffle

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Tomcat to use Windows NTLM authentication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439120/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-use-windows-ntlm-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a Single Sign-On (SSO) authentication or NTLM, then see below options:

- [Waffle/JNA](http://waffle.codeplex.com/)
- [Tomcat SPNEGO](http://tomcatspnego.codeplex.com/)
- [SPNEGO SF](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/)
- [Jespa (commercial)](http://www.ioplex.com/jespa.html)
- [Tomcat IIS
  Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html)
- [Samba JCIFs (obsolete, no
  NTLMv2)](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/ntlmhttpauth.html)

See also:

Windows Integrated Authentication using AD and Tomcat (no prompt to the users) [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/462261/Tomcat/Windwos-Integrated-Authentication-AD-Tomcat)

Configuring Tomcat for Windows Integrated Authentication [here](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/spnego_tomcat.html)